# Unable to remove maven using 'sudo apt-get remove maven2'

Tags: apt, maven-3

I want to upgrade to a newer version of `maven`. For that I first want to remove the existing version of `maven` in the computer as told [here](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-apache-maven-3-2-1-ubuntu-14-04/). I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove maven2
```

but it says:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove maven2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'maven2' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

Then I typed `mvn -version` just to make sure that `maven` is not present, but to my surprise I found:

```
$ mvn -version
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
* maven
* maven2
```

Unsure of what to do next, I did `locate maven` and deleted everything that was present in `/usr/share/maven-repo`. But after this, if i type `mvn -version`, it shows the same output that was shown above.

How can I automatically remove `maven`?

Comment: use `sudo apt-get purge maven2` and check again.

Comment: Unfortunately it is giving the same output what it was giving without using purge.

Comment: how did you install maven?

Comment: It seems `maven` is not installed in your system. You can skip the 1 step and go ahead with remaining steps in the tutorial you mentioned

Comment: try : sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove maven and sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove maven

Comment: @Private and @aneeshep: i did not install maven. I also dont know how its installed. I installed eclipse few hours ago. I am not sure if it automatically installs maven.
But if it is not installed then `mvn -version` should give some error message

Comment: @Private : no luck with the commands. 
" sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove maven and sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove maven "
They are giving the same output as `sudo apt-get remove maven`

Comment: @SanchitJain Maven isn't installed. `mvn -version` actually throws an error message, saying where you can get the program from.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it shows that you already removed it. You can go ahead and use:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get purge maven2
```

Run this command and problem will be resolved.

Comment: -1 That package isn't installed (`Package 'maven2' is not installed, so not removed`), so your command is moot.

Comment: worked for me yahoo

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get remove maven
```

instead of `maven2`.